# How can models be integrated into Workflow Manager?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, arcgis-workflow-manager

I have a ModelBuilder model that determines whether a field in a table contains null or duplicate values. The outputs of the model are two integer parameters, one with the count of nulls and one with the count of duplicates.

I have a workflow in [Workflow Manager](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_Workflow_Manager/003800000001000000/) that I would like to integrate the model into in order to implement logic branching.

Is there a way in Workflow Manager to:

1. Run the model as a step in a workflow
2. Examine the output of the model and branch into 1 of 2 logical workflow branches.

For 1) I assume that I must run the `JTXSteps.ExecuteGPTool` [custom step](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00380000001w000000.htm), is that correct?

For 2) (How) can I set the return code in the model? Must I refactor the model so that it only has one output parameter, or should I actually cause an error to occur for the return code to be non-zero? How can I use the return code to specify the logical branch to step into?

Comment: Don't know the answer to this one, but I am interested in the answer.  Also...do you know about using `sys.exit(n)` python statements to return codes that map to conditional return codes in WM?  It might save you from  having to compile, register a custom DLL  for something as mundane as checking for dupes/null.

Comment: No I hadn't thought of that, if you use something like that I'd be interested in hearing about it. How do you map the return codes to the appropriate next step?

Comment: I'll get something together and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add an executable step to workflow and configure it with python.exe as the Program and the arguments are your python script plus any WMX tokens that you want (*they will accessible in the python script via* `sys.argv`*).*
   [image]
2. In your python script, you'll do stuff and based on whatever condition...return a value.
   I've truncated some of the lines that I think might be sensitive, but you'll get the idea.  *And sorry for image screen shot of the code--for some reason, the python code was getting formatted horribly.*

   [image]
3. Then back in your Workflow, you double-click on the paths(lines) from your execute step to the next workflow step(s) to show path properties. Check the `Has Conditional Return Codes` checkbox. Add a new return code number that maps to the corresponding sys.exit(n) condition in your python script.  Repeat for each of your conditional steps.
   [image]

---

Credit to Jeremy Mirmelstein (Esri), who helped custom-configure this step and has been infinitely patient with my WMX questions.

Comment: Great example, thanks. I suppose it should be possible to use `sys.exit()` within a Calculate Value tool in a model if I wanted to use a model instead of a Python script. I'll have to play around with that.